# How to rollback another file when Excel is closed without saving?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a macro that writes some cell values to a text file. When any of these cell values change, the macro is triggered and the text output is updated.

However, if the user then decides to close the spreadsheet without saving the changes, the macro is not triggered, and the text output is not updated to the state before the changes were made.

A trivial example to clarify the issue:

- say cell B3 holds the string "Beer"
- the user then edits this cell to "Wine"
- the macro detects the change and updates the text file to "Wine"
- if the user then closes Excel without saving the changes, cell B3 obviously changes back to "Beer" (*although, since Excel is closing, this is visible only the next time the spreadsheet is opened*)
  … but the text file continues to show "Wine", because closing Excel without saving apparently does not cause any change event which can be used to fire the macro. Even calling the macro from the Workbook_BeforeClose or Workbook_Deactivate events does not refresh the text output from "Wine" back to "Beer"

Any suggestions how I can do a rollback of the text output?

Comment: If the file is closed without saving, the changes the user made will not be saved either. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

With just a little extra code I managed to make things work as follows:

- when Excel opens, the VBA macro creates the TEXTFILE and immediately copies that to a file TEXTCOPY
- when the user makes changes, TEXTFILE is updated, but TEXTCOPY is not
- when the user saves changes, TEXTCOPY is updated
- when the user quits Excel without saving, TEXTFILE is deleted and TEXTCOPY is renamed to TEXTFILE
- when the user closes Excel with saving, TEXTCOPY is deleted